# IOT Central Connected Field Service - Send Command

Tags: azure, crm, azure-iot-central

How do you send a command from Field Services to IOT central?
You can create a device, and there is the ability to define a command - but this doesn't connect to IOT central?

I would think you would use flow? But this doesn't use this UI at all?

[image: Command interface in IOT Central]

Comment: have you checked the official doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/devices/executecommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a legacy IoT Central app (i.e. not a preview one), you can use [this template](https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/4c543bafc55a4755b0f23195ad3db142/when-command-is-sent-from-cfs-run-the-command-on-iot-central/) in Power Automate (previously Flow). In case you haven't done so, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/field-service/cfs-iot-overview) is an excellent tutorial to get started with IoT Central and CFS.

In case you are using the preview features of central, you can use an HTTP request instead of the IoT Central block in Power Automate to use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/devices/executecommand).